# Cache database query result while accessing from Java Application

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a requirement that takes few user input and pulls data from DB for some kinda validation. The data it pulls is huge volume so i want this application not to touch DB if the result is in cache.

I thought of using secondary cache(EhCache) of hibernate but i think cache will not be in sync with DB if i make any changes to DB manually (i.e. not from Hibernate App which has cache config but from some other app/command prompt).

So is there any way to make this happen so the cache would be sync with DB ?
One more suggestion i wanted, If am pulling huge volume of data Is it a good way to work with hibernate ?

Comment: If you have 3rd party updates, then best solution is, have routines on DB to send those updates to cache. I don't think there is any other simple approach to solve this.

Comment: Yeah, Hibernate does a good job at handling big chunks of data because of it's Lazy loading.